# KivyMD on a Mac: running kitchen_sink raises an error in kivytoast.py

Tags: list, types, kivy, kivymd

On a Macbook Pro (Catalina), Python 3.8, interested in developing Android apps in Kivy using KivyMD. I took the following steps to install KivyMD:

- create the virtual environment (virtmd), then activated it (source /virtmd/bin/activate)
- in this virtual environment, installed the following via pip: Pillow, kivy
- git-cloned KivyMD as per the link suggested on the GitHub page
- Ran the pip install .

All this ran seamlessly with no hitch or errors. pip freeze shows the following installed items:

- certifi==2021.5.30
- charset-normalizer==2.0.4
- docutils==0.17.1
- idna==3.2
- Kivy==2.0.0
- Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
- kivymd @ file:///Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/KivyMD
- Pillow==8.3.1
- Pygments==2.9.0
- requests==2.26.0
- urllib3==1.26.6

I was following a Codemy video tutorial and noticed that the presenter's pip freeze showed 4 more entries:

- chardet==4.0.0
- kivy-deps.angle==0.3.0
- kivy-deps.glew==0.3.0
- kivy-deps.sdl2==0.3.1

Cd'ed into the /demos/kitchen_sink folder, ran 'python3 main.py' which failed, raising this error, the last few lines of the traceback appear to focus on a file called kivytoast.py:

```
   File "main.py", line 144, in <module>
     KitchenSinkApp().run()
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 944, in _run_prepare
     self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "main.py", line 65, in on_start
     Builder.load_file(
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 306, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 373, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 402, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 508, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 472, in execute_directives
     mod = __import__(package)
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/toast/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
     from .kivytoast import toast
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/toast/kivytoast/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
     from .kivytoast import toast
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/toast/kivytoast/kivytoast.py", line 72, in <module>
     class Toast(BaseDialog):
   File "/Users/robinhahn/PyProg/kvKivyMD/virtmd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/toast/kivytoast/kivytoast.py", line 90, in Toast
     self, instance_label: Label, texture_size: list[int, int]
 TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Still somewhat of a novice, and not really sure how to proceed from here.
ETA: I brought this up in VSCode and the last word:

**list**[int, int]

was squiggly-underlined, indicating it's the offending item. I have no idea what **'type' object is not subscriptable** means or how to fix it.

Thanks to all who read and ponder this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the same course right now and just got to that file with the same issue. I followed the path to the 'kivytoast.py' file and changed the following line (line 89):

```
    def label_check_texture_size(self, instance_label: Label, texture_size: list([int, int])) -> NoReturn:
```

The kivymd devs seemed to have made a mistake and did `list[int, int]` instead of `list([int,int])`. You could also just leave it as `[int,int]` and it would work the same since it is alread in list format. Goodluck with the rest of your course!

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you! So, that is what is meant by "enclose annotation type in quotes"... putting that [int,int] in parentheses. I did try literal quotes, but yeah, this is Python3.